# Store a variable on the .net server, away from client between http requests

Tags: .net, qr-code

I have a system that is going to implement dynamic QR-codes as a login validation option.
The system uses .net, JQuery, JS and ajax calls to the controllers that sits in the Web-Project.

1. Person who wants to login, scans the QR with their app (swedish BankID).
2. If the QR i valid (not to old and not to new, timewise), the person enter their personal code to login.
3. Person is no logged in.

The QR-Code is built with 3 parameters:
TimeElapsed
QRStart
QRSecret (this is a secret and should not be sent back to the client)

So i somehow need to store that QRSecret-variable on the server or somewhere where i can get access to it when i create a new QR-code, since i can't send it from the client with the http-request.

I should mention that the secret variable is unique to each login, so i need some way to store a variable for each user that is trying to login.

The variable only needs to be accessible for around 30 seconds, then it can be deleted.

I have read about Sessions and cookies, but i dont know if i need to implement sessions just to keep a variable on the server for 30 seconds, also if this is best practice or not.

Could i maybe use the cache to store the parameter on the server somehow? But then how do i find the correct variable for the next httpRequest?

When i wrote this i got to think about SignalR, maybe SignalR could be used to accomplish this? I have never really used it, except for a tutorial. :P

I would appretiate suggestions how to accomplish this task.

--

I have been trying to store the secret parameter in a class parameter. In the same class i have a method to Generate new QRCodes using the 3 parameters, where one is the secret one.
The newly generated QR-code is stored inside another class-parameter.
Then i have a method to retrieve the current QR-code that sits in that same parameter. The problem is that theese parameters are resetted between Http-Requests.

The idea was to start the operation of creating QR-codes with a http-request to a controller.
This controller then started a method that has a while loop that lasts for 30 seconds.
During theese 30 seconds, the method creates a new QR-code each second, that is stored inside the class parameter.

Then to have another loop on the client side, that sent http-requests every second (or maybe 0,5 sec).
The request accessed the controller that then ran another method in the same class where the QR-code parameter is stored, to return the current QR-Code to the client.

But this does not work unless i add the class as a Singelton service, which means that it will be shared across all instances of the class (which is not my intention since the secret variable is different for each user that is trying to login).

In the beginning i was thinking to create all 30 QR-codes at the same time and send them all back to the client. Then to loop through them, one each second. But i realized that this was a bad way of doing this, and not very secure.

I hope this is somewhat a good explanation to my problem.

Comment: Please confirm the intention, from the user's point of view - ie let's go back up a level - you want to use a QR code as a login method? Not as a login validation, but as the sole method to login.   Have you ever actually tried to scan a QR code?  It can take any time between 1 and 15 seconds (or longer) to recognise and scan the code - and you want to change that QR code every 0.5 sconds?

Comment: Im trying to implement Swedish BankID to login using dynamic QR and it needs to be updated every second. 0.5 sec was just if the timing got messed up.
And i think you are correct, it probibly is a login validation.
The user scans the QR with their BankID app
BankID processes the QR and if it is valid then the user 'ogin with their personal code.